# manipulate part of a letter without changing overall shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, text, font-manipulation

I am attempting to alter the letter "e" in the font Arial.  I want to match it in similarity to the "e" in Helvetica where the top of the tail is flat.

I am using the direct selection tool but yet the curvature of the "e" changes slightly.  Is there a way to flatten the tail without modifying the curvature.

Here is an image:[image]

Comment: In such cases in copy and paste in place (ctrl+F) the same letter. Then flip it to have the same curve at right side for reference. You can switch to wireframe mode, will be easier (Ctrl+Y)

Comment: I don't quite understand the technique of the "ctrl+F".

Comment: Sorry for being confusing. Copy to clipboard (Ctrl+C), Paste in place (Ctrl+F). You need a copy of letter to use as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you word the question, it seems that you're asking for a way to simply move the anchor point while somehow smoothly extending the curve. A curve is defined by the positions of its end points and its handles, so if you move an end point you will change the curve. That's how bézier curves work.

To do what you're trying to accomplish, copy your letter and paste in place above the original (`Ctl/Cmd-F`, which Illustrator calls "Paste in Front"). Change the color of your working copy -- the one you're going to modify -- and/or the original. Which colors don't matter, as long as they have good contrast. Lower the opacity of your working copy so that you can see the original through it.

Now make your changes, and use the visible original as a template to make the modified curve match the old one.

Comment: I did the ctr+f method and it works primly.  But now I am left with 2 shapes and one is a layer "above" the other.  Is there a way to combine both layers to be one path?  This is just for workflow neatness.

Comment: Simply delete the item you don't need, or hide it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do what Vnovak mentioned, minus the flipping.  I would simply leave the two letters on top of each other, oriented in the same direction, but change the color of the bottom e to differentiate it from the top e.  Then just match the curve of the top letter to the bottom letter, after you have moved the `Anchor Point` to make it level.

Both methods will work just fine for you.  I'm just putting in my 2 cents.

Comment: Is there a way to combine the 2 "e" groups into one?  If I deselect (unview) one of the "e" letters it reverts to the original.

Answer (score -2):

Click Object. Click Expand.
you can manipulate letters/tails with each blue point

Comment: To do what? Were have I to click Object? An answer in one line is too short.  Please explain better what you mean.